# Debian execute springboot app as service: service not found

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, debian, init.d

I follow this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-initd-service

My app repo:

```
└──╼ ls -l
total 67556
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1842 nov.   7 15:06 application.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69169161 nov.  12 07:50 importparcoursup.jar
┌─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
```

ln creation:

```
ln -s /var/apps/importsup/importparcoursup.jar /etc/init.d/importparcoursup
```

service start error:

```
┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ service importparcoursup start
Failed to start importparcoursup.service: Unit importparcoursup.service not found.
```

Is there something I forgot here ?

Here is some more commands I tried:

```
┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ /etc/init.d/importparcoursup start
-bash: /etc/init.d/importparcoursup: Permission non accordée

┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ sudo /etc/init.d/importparcoursup start
-bash: sudo : commande introuvable
```

Some more try today:

```
┌─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ ls -l /etc/init.d/
total 92
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1232 avril  7  2017 console-setup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3049 mai    4  2015 cron
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2813 mars   2  2018 dbus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6697 avril 18  2017 fail2ban
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3809 mars  22  2017 hwclock.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 nov.  12 15:34 importparcoursup -> /var/apps/importsup/importparcoursup.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2448 déc.  31  2016 irqbalance
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1479 mai   19  2016 keyboard-setup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2044 déc.  26  2016 kmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4597 sept. 17  2016 networking
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1846 juil. 25  2017 open-vm-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3624 févr. 23  2018 postfix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1191 nov.  22  2016 procps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4355 déc.  10  2017 rsync
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2868 janv. 19  2017 rsyslog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2578 juin  20  2016 snmpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4033 mars   1  2018 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6087 juil.  6  2017 udev
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1391 mai    6  2017 unattended-upgrades
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2757 nov.  23  2016 x11-common
┌─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ service importparcoursup start
Failed to start importparcoursup.service: Unit importparcoursup.service not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, I needed to reboot the server. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

try `chmod +x /var/apps/importsup/importparcoursup.jar` to make the file executable.

Comment: ┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ chmod +x /var/apps/importsup/importparcoursup.jar
┌─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ service importparcoursup start
Failed to start importparcoursup.service: Unit importparcoursup.service not found.
┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ sudo /etc/init.d/importparcoursup start
-bash: sudo : commande introuvable
┌─[✗]─[root@prodsb01:/var/apps/importsup]
└──╼ /etc/init.d/importparcoursup start
-bash: /etc/init.d/importparcoursup : impossible d'exécuter le fichier binaire : Erreur de format pour exec()

Comment: If I launch directly the jar ./importparcoursup.jar : it works, so the jar is executable